# JSON format error after jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving data on my nodejs app from a cordova app via a jQuery ajax call and it's formatted as

```
{
     "network[msisdn]": "+254738XXXXXX",
      "network[country]": "ke",
      "network[roaming]": "false",
      "network[simState]": "Ready",
      "network[network]": "HSPA",
      "network[simSerial]": "89254031021032011310",
      "network[subscriber]": "639031023201131",
      "network[service]": "GSM"
}
```

instead of the usual

```
{
  network: {    
              "msisdn" : "",
               ...
           }
}
```

I can loop through the object in the cordova phone app while accessing the nested keys like ***objectName***.network.msisdn but I cannot once I receive the data in my nodejs backend.

I am posting the data as shown below

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'http://'+$scope.api.host+':'+$scope.api.port+'/notices',
         method: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: $scope.storage.history[0]
      }).then(function(response){

          //! STORE THE RESULT IN THE RELEVANT OBJECT 
          $scope.storage.history[nextPos].locale = response;
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));

      });
```

I would like to access the sub keys from the object.

I have tried *Json.Parse(Json.stringify(objectName))* before posting the data,

I have also tried to post without the json dataType in the jQuery ajax call,

I have tried to *JSON.parse( )* the object in the back end all to no avail.

I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I dont understand, do you need the object to be formatted this way (`network[msisdn]`)?

Comment: Thanks for the concern Ahmad Bamieh, I need it formatted as network.msisdn but I am getting an object with the key "network[msisdn]" instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change how the data is returned, you can access it using string notation. Here is an example of using string notation and also a function that you could use to convert it to a nested object so that you can use dot notation.

```js
var exampleData = {
  "network[msisdn]": "+254738XXXXXX",
  "network[country]": "ke",
  "network[roaming]": "false",
  "network[simState]": "Ready",
  "network[network]": "HSPA",
  "network[simSerial]": "89254031021032011310",
  "network[subscriber]": "639031023201131",
  "network[service]": "GSM",
  "simpleKey": "simpleValue"
}

console.log(exampleData['network[country]']); // Logs -> ke

// This converts the keys in place
// it can be modified to return a new object instead
function convertKeys(data) {
  var pieces;
  for(var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      pieces = key.match(/(.+)\[(.+)]/);
      if (pieces) {
        data[pieces[1]] = data[pieces[1]] || {};
        data[pieces[1]][pieces[2]] = data[key];
        delete data[key];
      }
    }
  }
}

convertKeys(exampleData);
console.log(exampleData);
console.log(exampleData.network.simState); // Logs -> Ready
```

Comment: Thanks @rdbya, your solution works as is but once I substitute it with my data, I get the error: ** data.hasOwnProperty is not a function **

Comment: @rdbya, thank you very much.  I have worked out out by replacing that line of code with if(data[key]) as well as an if(pieces) ... Validation to prevent simple key value pairs from being manipulated.

Comment: @ianmin2 Glad you got it figured out. I updated my answer to include the changes you mentioned.

Comment: I just found out that I was getting the '.hasownproperty' is not defined error because I was using an arrow function as the parent function and they by default have no prototypes assigned to them.